# How to count the number of specific objects in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model called `User` and would like to count how many items are within the `following` object.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followers")
```

I have tried counting them using this line `followers_num = User.following.count()`, but I receive this error `'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'count'`.

I have also tried `followers_num = User.objects.all().count()`, but that returns the number of users.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the total number of following relations with:

```
User.following.through.objects.count()  # total number of following relations
```

If you want to add an extra attribute to the `User` objects with the number of `following`s *per* `User`, you can use:

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.annotate(
    num_following=Count('following')  # number of following per (!) user
)
```

---

> **Note**: A [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to itself is by default *symmetrical*, so that means that if *A* is a `following` of *B*, then *B* is automatically a `following` of *A*, you likely do not want that. You can turn this off with [**`symmetrical=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).

Comment: I added ```symmetrical=False``` and ran migrations, but I do not think anything happened. When I count how many are following and how many followers a user has, both values change if a new user follows that particular user. Will I have to delete all the existing users?

Comment: @econo: no, the number of following/follower relations are always the same. `symmetrical=False` is about how Django handles adding/removing/... items in such `ManyToManyField` relations.

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you want to get the user followers so you will First find the User

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user.following.all() # this will get you the followers of this user
```

user `count` to get their count, comment if that doesn't match what you need

Comment: This does not work for exactly the same reason as in the question: because `User.following` is a `ManyToManyDescriptor`, not a `QuerySet` or manager...

Comment: I am sorry I am wrong I didn't focus I will edit it